# Ubuntu on Windows - The End of Dual Boot?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Since this has come out, even though it is still in beta, does this put an end to the need for a dual boot computer? From what I've read, it certainly seems so, but after a date restricted Google search for newer answers with these keywords since the beta came out, no one seems to have directly addressed this issue.

I am aware of the post here https://askubuntu.com/questions/806819/bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows which dismissed the question as 'not about Ubuntu'. I am posting anyway, at the risk of having the question closed, because I think to claim this question is not about Ubuntu is just crazy wrong. It is very much an Ubuntu question. Where else would you ask it? On a Fedora forum?

Comment: Why would this be the end of dual boot? Does Wine prevent you from dualbooting Windows and Ubuntu? I don't think so...

Comment: We'd closed that question as OT because it was asking for speculation about when WSL would leave beta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer depends on what exactly you are using Ubuntu for. The Bash on Ubuntu on Windows is very convenient for accessing some of the command line tools. So for limited use cases, one might be fine using Windows and some of the command line tools and not have to dual boot.

However, it will not replace a dedicated Ubuntu install for a lot of Linux users. For one, it doesn't support a display server. For me, it just makes the times when I am forced to use windows more bearable. For people who like the user experience of Ubuntu better than Windows, Bash on Ubuntu on windows will probably not change their opinion.

On an ideological level many people choose to use Linux because it is free and open source and allows one to know everything the OS is doing and HOW it is doing it. In other words everyone has access to the source code and has the ability to modify it. Even though one can now access many of the great command line tools under Windows, Windows is proprietary and in opposition to the free software ideology.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and will accept it. I did a little more looking around after posting. When I look to the right at all the related questions with dual boot problems, and the fact that this is just a beta, I can foresee lots of future improvements - maybe including your display server - draining less ideological people away to Windows. There are a lot of things that don't work with Wine, but this effort has a huge marketing and talent machine behind it.

Comment: I agree there will be a lot of future improvements and some people will not see the need to dual boot. However, at least at this point, Microsoft has no intention of supporting GUI apps, i.e. a display server. see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq. Point is that WSL will never replace a whole linux distribution but aims to bring a wide variety of command line developer tools to windows. Though this may be enough for some people.